# Reading current motor speed, opOutput_Read

Tags: ev3, programming

I'm trying to read current motor speed using direct command:

```
Instruction        opOutput_Read (LAYER, NO, *SPEED, *TACHO)
Opcode             0xA8
Arguments          (Data8) LAYER – Specify chain layer number [0 - 3]
                   (Data8) NO – Port number [0 - 3]
                   (Data8) *SPEED – Output speed level detected, [-100 - 100]
                   (Data32) *TACHO – Current output tacho count
```

When I'm sending something like this:

```
unsigned char opOutput_Read[]
{
    0x0A, 0x00,              // bytes in message
    0x00, 0x00,              // message counter
    DIRECT_COMMAND_REPLY,    // tt   = Direct command with reply
    0x02, 0x00,              // 2 values will be returned
    0xA8,                    // opOutput_Read,
    GV0(0),                  // speed in return
    GV2(1)                   // tacho in return
};
```

I'm getting DIRECT_REPLY_ERROR. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The TACHO parameter is 4 bytes (32 bits).

```
(Data32) *TACHO – Current output tacho count
```

However, you have only allocated it 2 bytes (16 bits)

```
GV2(1)                   // tacho in return
```

Try using `GV4` instead of `GV2`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reserve 1 byte for the speed in return and 4 bytes for the tacho in return. However, the tacho has to be 32-bit-aligned and so you will need 3 padding bytes after the speed:

```
unsigned char opOutput_Read[]
{
    0x0A, 0x00,              // bytes in message
    0x00, 0x00,              // message counter
    DIRECT_COMMAND_REPLY,    // tt   = Direct command with reply
    0x08, 0x00,              // 8 values will be reserved
    0xA8,                    // opOutput_Read,
    GV0(0),                  // speed in return
    GV0(4)                   // tacho in return
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found answer here: http://topikachu.github.io/python-ev3/bytecodeexamples.html. It can be done using direct command:

```
Instruction        opInput_Device (CMD, ...)
Opcode             0x99
Arguments          (Data8) CMD => Specific command parameter documented below
                   CMD:READY_SI = 0x1D
                   Arguments
                       (Data8) LAYER – Specify chain layer number [0-3]
                       (Data8) NO – Port number
                       (Data8) TYPE – Specify device type (0 = Don’t change type)
                       (Data8) MODE – Device mode [0-7] (-1 = Don’t change mode)                           
                       (Data8) VALUES – Number of return values
                   Returns (Depending on number of data samples requested in (VALUES))
                       (DataF) VALUE1 – First value received from sensor in the specified mode
```

so to read speed from port A the one should send:

```
unsigned char opInput_Device[] =
{
    0x0D, 0x00,              //bbbb = bytes in message
    0x00, 0x00,              //mmmm = message counter
    DIRECT_COMMAND_REPLY,    //tt   = Direct command with reply
    0x04, 0x00,              //
    0x99, 0x1D,              //opInput_Device, READY_SI
    LC0(0),                  //Layer 0
    LC0(16),                 //16=PortA, 17=PortB, 18=PortC, 19=PortD
    LC0(0),                  //default type
    LC0(2),                  //mode 2
    LC0(1),                  //1 value will be returned
    0x60                     //local variable 0
};
```

Comment: For power values (first columns) I get responses:
  0 => 07000000 02000000 00,
  1 => 07000000 02000000 00,
  2 => 07000000 02000000 40,
  3 => 07000000 02000040 40,
  4 => 07000000 02000080 40,
  5 => 07000000 020000a0 40,
  6 => 07000000 020000c0 40,
  7 => 07000000 020000e0 40,
  8 => 07000000 02000000 41,
  9 => 07000000 02000010 41,
 10 => 07000000 02000020 41,
 11 => 07000000 02000030 41
but I'm not able to interpret them.